Unable to install mariadb python module
Since upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04, the module mariadbno longer works.
I tried

Install via pip3 install mariadb (got externally-managed-environment, with or without sudo)
Install via pip3 install mariadb --break-system-packages (got ERROR: Failed building wheel for mariadb after a long list a compilation errors)
More or less same result with pipx install mariadb (whole log on demand):


> Some possibly relevant errors from pip install:
>     mariadb/mariadb_codecs.c:59:20: error: conflicting types for ‘mariadb_extended_field_type’; have ‘int *(const MYSQL_FIELD *)’ {aka
> ‘int *(const struct st_mysql_field *)’}


What can I do?

Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64309549/10622916

Thank you, but it did not help.  (same problem of 'building 'wheels').
